# On the conditions defining physically acceptable motions in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Let $ x^\mu(\lambda) $ be a curve in Minkowski spacetime parametrized by some parameter $ \lambda\in \mathbb R $.

For $ x^\mu(\lambda) $ to represent a *physically acceptable motion* we usually require

1. that $ x^0(\lambda_1) < x^0(\lambda_2) $ for any $ \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 $;
2. that $ U^\mu(\lambda)U_\mu(\lambda)\leqq 0 $ for any $ \lambda $, where
   $$
   U^\mu = \frac{\mathrm dx^\mu(\lambda)}{\mathrm d\lambda}
   $$
   is the $ 4 $-velocity.

Requirement 1. seems reasonable to me. For instance, it assures that $ x^0(\lambda_1) = x^0(\lambda_2) $ and $ \vec x(\lambda_1)\neq \vec x(\lambda_2) $ can't hold when $ \lambda_1\neq \lambda_2 $. Here $ \vec x(\lambda) $ is the position vector $ (x^1(\lambda),x^2(\lambda),x^3(\lambda)) $.

On the other hand how can I visualize requirement 2.? I think that with 2. we want to be sure that given some $ \lambda $ and some parameter displacement $ \Delta\lambda $ then
$$
\bigl(x^1(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - x^1(\lambda)\bigr)^2 + \bigl(x^2(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - x^2(\lambda)\bigr)^2 + \bigl(x^3(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - x^3(\lambda)\bigr)^2 \leqq \bigl(x^0(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - x^0(\lambda)\bigr)^2 
$$
where more or less precisely
$$
x^0(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - x^0(\lambda) = c\bigl(t(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - t(\lambda)\bigr)
$$
where $ x^0(\lambda) = ct(\lambda) $. In this way we are sure that the distance squared $ \lVert\vec x(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - \vec x(\lambda)\rVert^2 $ does not exceed the distance squared $ d^2 $ traveled by a particle going at the speed of light.

But is 2. *equivalent* to this? (One direction is obvious, I'm struggling with the other).

Comment: Which $\mu$ in 1?

Comment: Oh, it's $ \mu = 0 $. I'm editing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the first condition is usually assumed in a stronger form
$$\frac{dx^0}{d\lambda}>0$$
which implies yours. That is because one wants to use $x^0$ as permitted differentiable parameter (the map $x^0=x^0(\lambda)$ is supposed to be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism at least, but your weaker condition permits $dx^0/d\lambda =0$ in discrete sets of the $\lambda$ domain: thinks of $x^0 = \lambda^3$).

Assuming the above stronger version of 1, we can re-parametrize the curve in the coordinate $x^0$ and your second condition reads
$$\left|\frac{d\vec{x}}{dx^0}\right| \leq 1\:.$$

Consider two instants $x^0=ct$ and $x^0= ct'$ with $t'>t$. It is possible to prove that, as you suspect, *there are no spacelike segments joining $x(ct)$ and $x(ct')$*. (This is the geometric statement you wrote in physical terms).

**PROOF**. Suppose that the vector in Minkowski spacetime $x(ct')-x(ct)$ is *spacelike*. Then we can arrange a Minkowski coordinate system $y^0,y^1,y^2,y^3$ with $y^3$ parallel to $x(ct')-x(ct)$ and origin in $x(ct)$ and such that $x(ct')$ has coordinates, let's say, $(0,0,0, k)$.
In coordinates $y^0,y^1,y^2,y^3$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$, consider the function $[t,t'] \ni s \mapsto f(s) := y(cs) \cdot e_0$
where

- $e_0$ is the unit vector parallel to $y^0$.
- $y=y(ct)$ is the representation in the said coordinates of the initial curve $x$.
- Is the standard Euclidean scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

By construction  $f(t)=0$ because $y(t)$ is the origin $(0,0,0,0)$ and
$f(t')=0$ because $y(t')- (0,0,0,0)$ is normal to $e_0$. Since the function is differentiable, there is $s_0 \in [t,t']$ where $f'(s_0)=0$. That is
$$\frac{dy}{ds} \cdot e_0 =0\:.$$
In other words the tangent vector to the curve $x=x(ct)$ in $s_0$ is parallel to the plane $y^0=0$ of the said Minkowski reference frame. Viewing this vector as a Minkowskian vector, it just mean that it is *spacelike*. This is impossible because it violates the condition 2 which says that the tangent vectors cannot be spacelike. QED

The fact that, if no spacelike segments join points on a curve then it has causal tangent vector everywhere is trivial from the fact that the light cone is closed.

Answer (score 0):

In special relativity, we say that the spacetime interval between two events is:
$$
\Delta s^2 = \Delta x^\mu \Delta x_\mu \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} > 0 & \text{space-like}\\ = 0 & \text{light-like} \\ < 0 & \text{time-like} \end{array}\right.
$$
where $\Delta x^\mu = x^\mu_f - x^\mu_i$. A better way to think about this --- because it generalizes to arbitrary coordinates and to *general* relaitivity --- is to define a vector in the tangent space of the initial event, $U^\mu$, such that it points along $\Delta x^\mu$. A *curve* through that event can then be called space-like, light-like, or time-like, depending on the inner product of its tangent vector with itself. The components of that tangent vector are $U^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu(\lambda)}{d\lambda}$, with:
$$
{\bf U} \cdot {\bf U} = U^\mu U _\mu \; \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} > 0 & \rightarrow \text{curve is space-like}\\ = 0 & \rightarrow \text{curve is light-like} \\ < 0 & \rightarrow \text{curve is time-like} \end{array}\right.
$$

So, a curve in Minkowski space is time-like (physically acceptable motion for a massive particle) if its tangent vector at every point has an inner product with itself that is negative. And a curve is  light-like (physically acceptable motion for a massless particle) if its tangent vector at every point has an inner product with itself that is zero.  Massive particles have curves that "stay inside of the light cone", while massless particles have curves that travel on the light cone.

This statement holds in general relativity, where the metric tensor $g$ defines the light cone at every event in spacetime (by defining the inner product in the tangent space to every event).  Considering the tangent vector, $U_\gamma$, to a curve, $\gamma$, at a point in spacetime, we can say that the (local) character of the curve is determined by:
$$
{\bf U}_\gamma \cdot {\bf U}_\gamma := g\left(U_\gamma, U_\gamma\right) = g_{\mu\nu}\, U_\gamma^\mu \,U_\gamma^\nu \; \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} > 0 & \text{space-like}\\ = 0 & \text{light-like} \\ < 0 & \text{time-like} \end{array}\right.
$$
While "curves" on the manifold of spacetime, as mathematical objects, could have *any* (smoothly changing) tangent vectors, physical particles must have curves (worldlines) that are either time-like at every point, or light-like at every point.